# Angular 4 Router: Getting redirected inside children's first route

Tags: angular

I have the following router :

```
const routes: Routes = {
    {
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: 'en'
    },
    {
      path: 'en',
      children: [
            {
                    path: '',
                    pathMatch: 'full',
                    redirectTo: 'homepage'
            },
            {
                    path: 'homepage',
                    component: HomeComponent
            },

        ]
    },

}
```

What I would like would be when I go to my `http://example.com` I got redirected to `/en/homepage` directly.
Right now, what's happening is that I got redirected to `/en` only. What am I missing in my router config ?

Comment: redirectTo: '/en' and redirectTo: '/en/homepage'. The redirects aren't relative by default like it seems you're expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

updated this answer try like this in your route file and module file like below it will be working correctly for me.

**home.route.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'en'
    },
    {
        path: 'en',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: 'homepage'
            },
            {
                path: 'homepage',
                component: HomeComponent
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

**module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routes } from './home.route';
const HOME_STATES = [
    ...routes
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(HOME_STATES, { useHash: true })
    ]
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: if you go to enter this url http://example.com it will be automatically reload to http://example.com/en only ?

Comment: yep indeed, while I would like it to go to /en/homepage

Comment: @Scipion i updated answer can you check and try like above ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is redirect to required path:

```
{
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: '/en/homepage'
}
```

Comment: What if I am adding the /homepage route at runtime in my appComponent ?

Comment: Route will redirect to the path you mentioned in redirectTo property without any validation.